# AWS EC2 magically routes to S3 using private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I've deployed an EKS cluster, each of the EC2 instances has its own public ip and all attached to the same VPC.
The routing table for each of the EC2 instances subnets looks as follows:

```
Destination     | Target
----------------------------------------
192.168.0.0/16  | local
0.0.0.0/0       | igw-06d8c484aaba8d136
```

So if I understand correctly, every time I read from an S3 bucket (in the same region or not), it should be routed using the internet gateway to the internet, and if that's the case, **I should see charges for it**.

**However**, I don't see any charges for it, I tough that maybe AWS network magically taking care of these routings but they actually provide [another solution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) and these rules aren't in any of the routing tables.

Not that I'm against free services, but I prefer to understand this before reading lots of data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are still in the AWS free tier (12 months free) with 20,000 get requests free and 2,000 put requests free [source](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=categories%23storage)

EDIT:
As you say the free stuff does appear in cost explorer.

However, if EC2 instance and S3 bucket are in the same region, the requests should be free regardless of endpoints, if you have this setup, I think that's the explanation.

This [article](https://www.sumologic.com/insight/s3-cost-optimization/) summarises it quite nicely.

I would recommend setting up an s3 endpoint if you wish to keep internal transfer costs down after your free tier expires though, it's also great for performance.

Comment: Free tier usage shows up in cost explorer, these don't. Which makes me think it's treated as "internal usage".

Comment: Ah I see, have edited above, I guess the bucket and instance are in the same region?

Comment: NOTE: Why do you need public ip for the worker node instances ? this isn't a good practice unless you need to have a very very good uniq reason that I can't think of ..
As per your question, in the same region there are not charges to s3 , and in case you want to have better performance and to not be charged on your NAT, use the S3 endpoint

Comment: @MickeyHovel I've used the [EKS Getting started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) for creating the EKS cluster, and apparently worker nodes with public IP is the default. I know about the Gateway VPC endpoint, I'm just trying to understand how the network rules apply here, with this existing architecture.

Comment: @matt45uk the bucket and the EC2 instances are indeed in the same region. But that doesn't explain how the Internet gateway routed packets find themselves routed to the S3 service using private IP.

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't. Have you tried ping/nslookup e.g. ```ping s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
PING s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com (52.95.149.72) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com (52.95.149.72): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=0.172 ms
64 bytes from s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com (52.95.149.72): icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=0.258 ms
^@^@64 bytes from s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com (52.95.149.72): icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=0.324 ms```